# Is there a way to bind to the load() event of an image after changing it's src?

Tags: jquery, image, load

I have an image `<img id='my_img' src='img1.png'>` and a button.
Clicking the button does the following:

```
$('#my_img').attr('src','img2.png')
```

This second image (img2.png) is fairly large, and I want to know when it is fully loaded (i.e. .load() event).
I tried to use .live, .bind, and .complete but none seem to fire.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Amit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the load event only fires once per img tag.  But you can easily make a new image, and load that with a new load handler.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  $('#my_img').attr('src', img.src);
};
img.src = 'img2.png';
```

Once it's loaded you can set the src of the image on your page and it will pull instantly from the browser cache.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I guess there is no way to avoid creating a new image then.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('<img id="myimg" src="1.png" /><a href="" id="clickme">click</a>').appendTo('body');

$('#clickme').click(function() {
    // replace the old img with a new one and define onLoad for the new img
    var newImg = $('<img />')
        .bind('load', function() {
            alert('2nd img loaded');
        })
        .attr('src', '2.png');
    $('#myimg').replaceWith(newImg);
    return false;
});
```