# Bind image load errors in the <head>

Tags: jquery, image, onerror

[Is there a way to bind to the load() event of an image after changing it's src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800110/is-there-a-way-to-bind-to-the-load-event-of-an-image-after-changing-its-src) is 2 years old

[How to remove future broken image using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440704/how-to-remove-future-broken-image-using-jquery) has not been answered successfully

**NOTE:** I am fully aware of how to handle the image failing to load AS it is loading - I could add a placeholder image and then assign the onerror handler in the same loop I am assigning the actual src like [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/PrQ2Q/)

I am trying to EITHER run down a page of images and handle already failed images (not optimal) OR
have jQuery bind all img.onerror in given selector before the page is loading (Better solution)

So I thought of ON in the head:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4etet/)

```
$("figure img").on("error",function () {
  console.log("error")  
  $(this).parents(".content-holder").removeClass("p-alt");
  $(this).parents("figure").remove();
});
```

but that does not work - nothing removed and nothing in the console.

I have looked at naturalWidth, but that is not supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

how can you bind an event to an element that doesn't exist at that point? `$("figure img")` does not select anything as those elements don't exist on the page yet.

Comment: "live" was/is used to monitor the DOM for objects, it is not that far-fetched to think the replacement "on" could do the same and react to the appearance of an image tag in the DOM, intercept it and attach the event handler before the src request was triggered. If I insert an image using append, that is what will happen.